# Are multiple defs allowed in SVG documents?

Tags: svg

I want to make sure that I follow the standards.
Is it allowed to have multiple defs in ONE SVG document?

And are nested svgs allowed to have defs?

```
<svg>
 <defs></defs>
 <svg>
  <defs></defs>
 </svg>
</svg>
```

I couldnt find anything in the specs related to this

Comment: Great question!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes it is allowed, but bear in mind that `id`s must still be unique within the entire document. The behaviour of the example below is undefined/browser-dependent:

```html
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg width="800px" height="300px"
           xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

        <defs>
          <linearGradient id="Gradient01">
            <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#39F" />
            <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#F3F" />
          </linearGradient>
        </defs>

        <rect x="10" y="10" width="60" height="10" 
              fill="url(#Gradient01)" />
        <svg width="380px" height="330px"      
             xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

        <defs>
          <linearGradient id="Gradient01">
            <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#39F" />
            <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#F3F" />
          </linearGradient>
        </defs>

        <rect x="250" y="250" width="160" height="110" 
              fill="url(#Gradient01)" />
        </svg>
      </svg>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: The main answer about it being allowed is correct.  But the rest about "different namespaces" is completely wrong.  `id` attributes must be unique in a document. Having two defs sections doesn't change that. If you have duplicate `id` attributes you get undefined (and browser dependent) results. For proof, try viewing this example in Chrome, then in Firefox.